# How to implement snap grid with cross cursor in pyqt?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I want to draw a snap grid like the picture as bellow,I can draw the background point, but I don't know how to snap  the grid point while mouse moving,Could here someone know how to do it?Thanks.

**My Sample Code**
it start very slow and sometime stuck.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

import math

from qtpy.QtWidgets import *
from qtpy.QtCore import *
from qtpy.QtGui import *

class Point(QGraphicsItem):
    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        return QRectF(-3, -3, 6, 6)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: 'QStyleOptionGraphicsItem', widget) -> None:
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.boundingRect())

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.BspTreeIndex)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.lightGray)
        self.initScene()

    def initScene(self):
        y = x =  np.arange(1000*100, step=50)
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        for px, py in zip(xx.flatten(), yy.flatten()):
            point = Point()
            point.setPos(px, py)
            self.addItem(point)

    def wheelEvent(self, event: 'QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent') -> None:
        factor = math.pow(2.718, event.delta()/360)
        factorRatio = self.views()[0].transform().scale(factor, factor).mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width()
        if factorRatio < 0.3 or factorRatio > 5:
            return

        self.views()[0].scale(factor, factor)
        return super().wheelEvent(event)

app  = QApplication([])
view = QGraphicsView()
view.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
view.setScene(Scene())
view.resize(500, 500)
view.show()
app.exec()
```

**Wanted the snap grid**
[image]

Comment: The code above only draws the grid (and not in a very optimal way, as far as I can see), where is the part in which you add those lines? How should that work? We can help you with the snap, but we cannot implement the whole interaction and drawing for you.

Comment: The line can  use two points to draw, So the major question is how to snap nearest  grid point when mouse hover it. When mouse click it, record the first point, and then mouse click another point, record second point, and draw a line with two points.I had not draw those lines for that picture was captured from EDA software,I just want to know how to snap the points,the rest I think will be easy.

Comment: Sorry, but your reputation and membership say that you should already know that we don't just code for "how can I do xyz". Your example shows no attempt at all to even *create* those points and lines. That said, since you want to add new points and update lines based on mouse events, and your grid is quite simple (based on 50 steps coordinates), just get the mouse press position and see if its coordinates are within the range of those steps: eg. `if x % 50 > 25: x += 50 - x % 50`.

Comment: Can you give me some article that I can better to do it.I think my solution is not very good.

Comment: *What* solution? If you tried to implement it, then [edit] your question and provide a [mre] that includes *that* aspect.